# Variable with .size won't show correct number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this bit of code

```
$('.workedu_forms').size();
```

to calculate how many .workedu_forms that exist. Using only that will for example return the value 2 without problems.

However, if I put that code into a variable like this

```
var count = $('.workedu_forms').size();
```

count returns 0, why does it do that and how can I bypass that and put the code into a variable?

Comment: try `$('.workedu_forms').length`

Comment: In what context are each of the 2 snippets used? It could be that the 2nd with `var count` is executed before the elements actually exist.

Comment: Post your html. Then only we could answer your question entirely.

Comment: Are you clearing that variable count anywhere else in your code.? Post your Jquery code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `$('.workedu_forms').size();` because .size() was deprecated.

Use `.length` instead.

```
$('.workedu_forms').length;
```

Please read this : [.size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/)

Comment: that doesn't mean it will give a wrong answer isn't it.... either it is not there or if it is there it should work

Comment: from the doc `The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes of course, But it is a good practice and a must thing to exclude the deprecated ones while developing.

Comment: that is right but the issue OP is asking is not related to it.... if `size()` is not working then why should `.length`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Op did not post any html. Until he post html, This would be a good snippet for him to keep in mind. We shall update the answer once he posted the html. fingers are shivering while conversing with an expert. :)